# Copy row from one workbook to another VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, row

I'm facing an issue, where I'm trying to go through the list of values, find each value in other workbook, copy entire row where this value is, and paste it back to first workbook, to other sheet, one after the other.
FoundCell.row is giving me correct row values that I need to copy - but copying, and pasting it, here's where it doesn't work.

Code is written in workbook where the list of words I'm searching is.
The other workbook opens in this code, based on the current date (there is new extract everyday)

```
Sub OpenCopy()
Dim report As Workbook
Dim extract As Workbook
Dim aw As Workbook
Dim row As Integer

Dim OpenPath As String
Dim OpenName As String
OpenPath = "C:\\Users\\Noon\\Desktop"
OpenName = OpenPath & "Users\_" & Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=OpenName

Dim c As Range
*'c is a name of user I'm trying to find in other workbook, and copy row of his data back to the first *workbook

Dim FoundCell As Range
On Error Resume Next

        For Each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Status").UsedRange.Columns("A").Cells *'this goes through the list of users*

            Set FoundCell = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DSV-Users").Range("A:A").Find(What:=c) *'here im searching other workbook for this specific word  *

            ActiveWorkbook.Row(FoundCell.row).EntireRow.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(c.row & ", 1") *'here I'm stuck, it wont copy row where I found the value, and ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") is where I'm trying to paste it*

        Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really need to copy the **entire** row? that's more than 16000 cells... Try copy/pasting only the delimited data.

Comment: I tried Range("A" & FoundCell.row & ":" & "BC" & FoundCell.row) instead of Row(FoundCell.row).EntireRow but it didn't work either